# Java Android how can I make ImageView darker onClick

Tags: java, android, imageview

As an iOS developer told me, iOS make an image darker when somebody tap it (I don't know how true it is) so I need the same thing.

as I understand, I need a usual selector.xml to make a drawable with different states.
What I need is to darken the image in a simple way, may be in xml-drawable somehow so I don't have to use Photoshop in which I have no skill.

Is there a way to do so on xml-level?

Comment: A possibility would be to overlay your imageview with another view and then have the selector on the view. In the selector you could then just make a darker background when selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You May Put a `dark rectangle` behind your bitmap and set the `Bitmap's` `Opacity` instead of trying in `xml`.

Comment: @Homo sapiens : what do you mean by dark rectangle?

Comment: What if the image is not rectangle, and it has some transparency around.? If we put a dark rectangle then the image would get the effect but the transparent area would look weird.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the following code in your java class:

```
mView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(<Color code of your choice>), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
```

This line above changes the color of the view to to a share of color you suggest in Color.parseColor() and a shade like how you define it using PorterDuff.Mode. Call the above code on click of a button to check if the color change is taking effect.

Comment: `getBackground()` may return null, so check null before use.

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
private void darkenImage(ImageView imageView)
{
    imageView.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(123, 123, 123), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}

private void undarkenImage(ImageView imageView)
{
    imageView.clearColorFilter();
}

private boolean isImageDarkened(ImageView image)
{
    return image.getColorFilter() != null;
}
```

works really well !

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that adding a clickListener to your Image...

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView image = (ImageView)v;
                image.setImageAlpha(alpha);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Right but you definitely will need to put a darker rectangle or an image with dark color behind your view then by changing the alpha of the view you will get the desired effect.